# cannot find nativescript demo app folder path in my mobilephone

Tags: nativescript

I have build a demo app in my phone and in file module I cannot find the file in my phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are writing the image to app / documents directory which will be accessible only to the app itself. It won't be visible to other apps in the phone.

You have to use external storage directory if you want it to be listed by other file manager apps.